# Given a full path of an image file, how to get its thumbnail?

Tags: android, android-image

It seems the answers I searched online (including stackoverflow.com) get the image file id through gallery selection.

I have created my own file explorer.
Then how to do that?

I can create my own small size image; but I think it would be faster if we can make use of an exisiting thumbnail; and if it does not exist, I would prefer to create a thumbnail that is saved for later use.

[Update:]
OK, thanks for advice. So I will not create a thumbnail in the device, to avoid to use too much space.
Then is is better to do two steps:
Step 1: look for an exisiting thumbnail for the image file if it exists.
Step 2: if no thumbnail exists, then create my own small size bitmap (not save the it).

Then how to do Step 1, if I do not use the Gallery intent?

[Update 2:]
I also want to get the thumbnail of a video file.
I can use MediaMetadataRetriever to get a frame at any point of time, and rescale the image to a thumbnail. But I find it is very slow: I have 4 video files in the folder, and I can sense the delay.

So I think the better way to retrieve an existing thumbnail.
If I only know the file path and file name, how can I get it?
I think this question is the same as my original one, just it has more sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using specific files for tumbnail, especially not creating tumbnails. What if the user has a lot of images and you store a tumbnail of each picture which gets viewed in your explorer. That would generated a whole lot of duplicated and unwanted data. The calculations from resizing the images each time overweighs the amount of data that would need to be stored.

I would suggest you have a default icon on images in the explorer and then resizing the images in a diffrent thread, replacing your default tumbnail as they are resized.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If I want to make use of an existing thumbnail (if exists), is it possible?

Comment: I don't really see how that's possible, Java in general have very bad support for retrieving detailed information about files. Even on computers it can be tricky to get informations about thumbnails and such.

Answer (score 0):

You could downsize the existing images on the fly:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path, opts);
int width = opts.outWidth;
int height = opts.outHeight;
```

then

```
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
opts.inDither = true;
opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

opts.inSampleSize = (int)Math.pow(2.0,Math.floor(Math.log(scale_factor)/Math.log(2)));//for example double scale_factor=(double)width/desired_dimension;
```

and finally:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path,opts);
```

You could load in a separate thread ranges of existing files and update only those ones when needed.

Comment: Thanks. I knew how to create a small size bitmap. I just thought it might be better to use an exisiting thumbnail if it exisits? Is it possible to retrieve it when I do not use the Gallery intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThumbnailUtils. Look up the this utility method. Probably fits your need without much hassles. Creating duplicate downsized images is a bad design as that it will end up unnecessary data.

```
Bitmap resizedImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(rescaledImage, imagePixel, imagePixel);
```

Comment: Personally I think if I first get a bitmap of "rescaledImage" (I need to resize it since many original images have a large size), then use extractThumbnail to get a smaller size, I would do it in one step suggested by Eudhan.

Comment: well.. you dont need a rescaled image. You can throw in any image you want in there and you give it a height and width .. and you will get that image. This code is mine and I did not change the variable thats all